# Как определить длинное нажатие в Android?

Tags: события, android

Класс `MotionEvent` понимает только 3 состояния:

- `ACTION_DOWN`,
- `ACTION_MOVE`,
- `ACTION_UP`.

Как определить длинное нажатие, например, для вызова контекстного меню для любого `view`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) позволяет отслеживать долгие нажатия:

```
public class X extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: большое спасибо. думаю это то что мне надо.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте [setOnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)):

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Здесь нужный обработчик
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: За это спасибо. Но, к сожалению, кроме факта нажатия, еще нужно определить координаты нажатия внутри View (как в MotionEvent), я так понимаю, onLongClick не сможет этого сделать.